# Python unable to find installed modules on work computer -Windows OS

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have this python script I wrote that works fine on my computer at home, where I'm admin. I've tried using it at work (uses network drive and I am not admin), and I keep running into this problem that any module I use isn't recognized.

I installed each package with python -m pip install. When I run python from a command prompt, I am able to import and use each package; however, when I try to run code with VS code, it returns "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_______'.

I've manually chosen an interpreter, and even specified the absolute path to site-packages for the "PYTHONPATH" property of "env" in the launch.json file. I also even tried moving the program to site-packages and it still couldn't find the packages.

Let me know if there's any other info I need to include. I've scoured the online sources for weeks as best I can for a similar issue, but none of the answers I've found have worked so far. Any help is immensely appreciated as I would really love to get this script working.

```
# MMDG RECEIPT RENAMER
# Author: RillienCot, CrookedKaptain
# 11/2021

import os
from io import StringIO
import datetime
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
import win32com.client as wcom

from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser

#Directory Definitions
unpBatchDir = r'LOCATION OF UNPROCESSED BATCHES'
pBatchDir = r'LOCATION OF PROCESSED BATCHES'
indivDir = r'FINAL LOCATION OF ALL INDIVIDUAL RECEIPTS'

#Dictionary for Fund IDs to Fund Short Formats
fundDict = {
    "1 GenOps": "AA",
    "2 Parkinson": "DfPD"
}

#Loop through all .doc files in directory
#Save all found files as PDFs, remove word file
for file in os.listdir(unpBatchDir):
    if file.endswith(".doc"):
        filepath = os.path.join(unpBatchDir, file)
        file = file.replace('.doc', '')
        newFilePath = os.path.join(unpBatchDir, file + '.pdf') #Create new pdf doc with same name as word doc
        #Start Word and open .doc
        word = wcom.Dispatch('Word.Application')
        doc = word.Documents.Open(filepath)
        #Save .doc as PDF
        doc.SaveAs(newFilePath, FileFormat = 17)
        #Close document, exit word, and remove .doc file
        doc.Close()
        word.Quit()
        os.remove(filepath)

#Split PDF Batch in single page PDFs, store split pages in new indivDir, move batch to processed folder
for file in os.listdir(unpBatchDir):
    #iterate through each pdf file in the directory
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        filePath = os.path.join(unpBatchDir, file)
        batchPDF = PdfFileReader(filePath)

        #Split pages from source PDF
        for pageNum in range(batchPDF.numPages):
            pdfWriter = PdfFileWriter()
            indivFileNaming = "{}/Receipt #{}.pdf".format(indivDir,pageNum)
            pdfWriter.addPage(batchPDF.getPage(pageNum))

            #Save split pages to indivDir
            with open(indivFileNaming, 'wb') as indivFile:
                pdfWriter.write(indivFile)
        
        #Move batch to processed folder
        os.rename(filePath, os.path.join(pBatchDir, file))

#loop through each filename found in the directory location
#rename the file
for filename in os.listdir(indivDir):
    #add all pdf filenames to the filenames list
    # loop through all the filenames to open each one
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        path = os.path.join(indivDir, filename)

        #Extract text from file
        output_string = StringIO()
        with open(path, 'rb') as in_file:
            parser = PDFParser(in_file)
            doc = PDFDocument(parser)
            rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
            device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
            for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
                interpreter.process_page(page)
        textList = output_string.getvalue().splitlines()

        for line in textList:
            if line == "":
                textList.remove(line)

        #get name
        name = textList[0].strip()
        
        #get date and convert to "MMDDYY" format
        date = textList[1]
        dateObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(textList[1].strip(), "%B %d, %Y")
        date = dateObject.strftime("%m%d%y")

        #Get Fund ID and convert to short format for naming
        fund = fundDict[textList[2].strip()]

        #Name and Path for New File
        newFilename = fund + " - " + name + " - " + date + ".pdf"

        os.rename(path, os.path.join(indivDir, newFilename))
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not selected the proper python interpreter in the VSCode.

While you can execute the python file successfully in the command prompt, you should have installed the packages in the global python environment. But you have not selected this python environment in the VSCode.

You can click the python interpreter at the bottom-left on the VSCode to switch the python interpreter.

[image]

You can execute `pip show {packagename}` to get where the package has been installed, `pip --version` to get which pip you are using, and `print(sys.prefix)` to get which python environment you are using.